# Could not click elements with Selenium Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to open this webpage

https://albo-on-line.comune.verona.it/web/servizi/albo-pretorio

with this code:

```py
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

url = "https://albo-on-line.comune.verona.it/web/servizi/albo-pretorio"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

cookies = driver.find_element(By.xpath('//*[@id="cookie-privacy-close"]')).click()

determinazioni = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="_menucontroller_WAR_maggiolialbopretorioportlet_MenuItem9"]')).click()
```

but no success

can you help me ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing here to improve:

1. Your syntax is wrong.
   Instead of `driver.find_element(By.xpath('//*[@id="cookie-privacy-close"]'))` it should be `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cookie-privacy-close"]')`
2. You should use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits, not `implicitly_wait`
3. Since you locating these elements by their ID it's better to locate these elements by ID, not by XPath.

The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://albo-on-line.comune.verona.it/web/servizi/albo-pretorio"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'cookie-privacy-close'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, '_menucontroller_WAR_maggiolialbopretorioportlet_MenuItem9'))).click()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi thx for suggestion I've used your code it works but the webpage after open it immediately  close

Comment: ok sorry I'm new  and I'm trying to learn

Comment: I understand. This is why I gave you the link above to make you learn some basic roles of this forum. Actually not just this forum...